# rails 4 routes constraints condition error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have used Rails 3.0 with routes.rb it works well.But now,I upgraded Rails to 4.0 then this routes causes the No route matches [GET] "/project/12323/payment"

```
match "project/:id/payment" => "project#payment", :as => "project_payment", :via      => :get, :constraints => { :protocol => Rails.env.production? ? 'https' : 'http' }
```

If I remove `:constraints => { :protocol => Rails.env.production? ? 'https' : 'http' }`, again it works.I guess the problem is about :constraints syntax but I don't sure.

Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: are you accessing it in production? what protocol are you using?

Comment: I'm accessing it in development but it also has to work with 'http'

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.  Trying changing `https` and `http` to `https://` and `http://`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 'https', say /https/

That worked for me.